# C++ API unhandled exception: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, dolphindb

In VS2019 (C++ API ), the same code completed under Release compiling but raised an error under DEBUG compiling.

The code is as below:

```py
#include "include\DolphinDB.h"
#include "include\Util.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace dolphindb;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    string host = "192.168.2.114";
    int port = 8848;
    string username = "admin";
    string password = "123456";
    DBConnection conn;
    ConstantSP vector;
    int size=0;

    std::cout << "Connecting DolphinDB: [" << host << ":" << port << "]  Username:[" << username << "] Password:[" << password << "]" << endl;
    bool ret = conn.connect(host, port,username,password);
    if (!ret) {
        cout << "Failed to connect to the server" << endl;
        //getchar();
        //return 0;
        goto END_APP;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Had connected to DolphinDB server [" << host << ":" << port << "] Username=["<<username<<"]\n";
    }
    //ConstantSP vector = conn.run("`IBM`GOOG`YHOO");
    vector = conn.run("today();now()");
    size = vector->rows();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout << vector->getString(i) << endl;

END_APP: getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The error is as follows:

unhandled exception: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc, located at memory 0x000000B29C97EE30.

Comment: Have you run through the debugger to see where the exception is being thrown? You should be able to see which line is causing the problem in the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

The library used now is the release version. If the project uses debug, the library also needs to be compiled with the debug version.